# Microsoft Graph API - "Needs admin approval" when accessing Assignment API with non-admin accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently facing an issue while working on a Teams Widget that utilizes the Microsoft Graph API, specifically the Assignment API. My objective is to enable students and teachers to access and interact with assignments. However, I'm encountering a problem where I consistently receive a "needs admin approval" message when attempting to log in with either a student or a teacher account.

Here's the current setup I have in place:

- Admin Account: I possess an account with admin rights, and when I log
  in using this account, the Assignment API works as expected.
- Student    Account: I have created a student account with the "Office
  365 A1 for    students" permission.
- Teacher Account: I have created    a teacher    account with the
  "Office 365 A1 for faculty" permission.

To facilitate API access, I have created a new application and assigned it the necessary Education permissions as outlined in the Microsoft Graph API documentation.

Despite diligently following the documentation and granting the required permissions, I continue to encounter the "needs admin approval" message when attempting to log in using either the student or teacher account. Moreover, upon inspecting the accessToken, I noticed that the required permissions are not visible, indicating a potential issue with their assignment.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance on identifying what might be going wrong in this setup. Is there something I have overlooked or an additional configuration step required to allow non-admin accounts to access the Assignment API without relying on admin approval?

I have tried everything documented [here](https://appfluence.com/help/article/microsoft-teams-need-admin-approval/).

Furthermore, I am unable to update the admin consent settings to allow users to request admin consent. The "Save" button is disabled when trying to modify this setting.

[image: Admin consent settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an **Azure AD Application and added API permissions** for sample like below:

[image]

Now, I tried to **authorize users** using the below endpoint;

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms 
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

I got the **same error** when I tried to sign in as user:

[image]

The error ***"Need admin approval"*** usually occurs if the admin has not consented to the permissions added to the application or if you are passing incorrect permissions while authorizing the users and those permissions are not added to the application.

**To resolve the error,** Grant Tenant-Wide Admin Consent by signing as Global Admin or Grant Admin Consent in the Portal.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/adminconsent?client_id=ClientID
```

[image]

Once you click on Accept, the Admin consent will be granted to the API permissions successfully.

[image]

If you don't want to give all the users consent to access the API, then you can make use of **Admin Consent Workflow**:

*Go to Enterprise Applications -> Consent and permissions -> Admin consent settings*

[image]

After the above settings, the user will get **Approval Required screen** and can request Admin for the consent and if the admin approves the user can access the API:

[image]

Now, I am able to access the API without any error like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, check the below:

- Verify that the scope of the permissions in authentication code matches to the scope of the permissions you have given to the application.
- In your case, you would need to specify the appropriate permissions related to education as you are working on an application that interacts with education-related.
- After admin consent is granted to the permissions wait for few seconds and try.

Comment: I have removed permissions from my nodejs backend. It does not ask for permissions anymore and is allowing me to login and view assignments as assignment permissions are already being assigned from admin. But, it's not allowing me to save "Enterprise Applications -> Consent and permissions -> Admin consent settings". Save is disabled.

Comment: What role do you have?

Comment: I am trying to update that from admin account.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have Global Admin role?

Comment: Yes, I have Global Administrator role.

Comment: Can you attach the snip of the Admin consent settings? and if the app does not ask for permissions and able to access then there is no need of doing settings on Enterprise Applications.

Comment: Please see edited question for image. I want user to ask for permissions if they are not assigned. For now, it's just a work around that user is logging in and seeing error message to contact administrator. For that, I guess I need this setting.

Comment: From your screenshot you are already enabled the setting. You can add reviewers to accept the request and save

Comment: I can't save this setting. You can see Save button disabled at top left.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254521/discussion-between-rukmini-and-sz).